# How can I add a frame as a toolbar item in toolbar xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, toolbaritems

Image:

[image]

I would like to add a frame to toolbar in Xamarin forms. But toolbar is not accepting.

Comment: There is already a Custom Renderer you can use this : https://github.com/CrossGeeks/ToolbarItemBadgeSample

Comment: It is a badgeview with image in toollbar. Need to add a image which is in a circular frame and color of the frame changes dynamically.

Comment: This same code you can modify by keeping the circular view and show image instead of count and don't add image.

Comment: I have added an image. I am expecting like that.

Comment: I am confused about what you want. What effect do you really want? Could you share your basic code with the details of the problem?

Comment: Frame frame = new Frame
            {
                CornerRadius = 15,
                HeightRequest = 30,
                WidthRequest = 30,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                Margin = 0,
                Padding     = 0,
                BorderColor = Color.Green,
              Content = UserImage       
            }; trying to add this to toolbar.

Comment: Could you provide code snippet about how to add this frame to toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a frame as a Toolbar Item.

You can use, for example the TitleView and customize the whole NavigationView yourself.

For example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TitleViewSample"
             x:Class="TitleViewSample.MainPage">

<NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
             <Label Text="Hello World" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            <Frame BackgroundColor="Yellow" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: But I am having a badge control in toolbar which should work only if it is toolbar item. I need to display my image which is in a circular frame and the color the frame changes dynamically and it should be aligned to the right of badge control.